# count($nameArray) is not returning correct value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$nameArray = array("Bob", "John", "Ben", "Mike");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameArray); $i++){
    $name = $nameArray[$i];
    $nameArray[$name] = strlen($nameArray[$i]);
    echo $nameArray[$i]."'s name is ".$nameArray[$name]." letters long <br>";
}
```

Why is `count($nameArray)` returning 8 instead of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have declare array that time it is having numeric indexes as

```
Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => John [2] => Ben [3] => Mike )
```

After that you are pushing new values with new index using following statement:

```
 $nameArray[$name] = strlen($nameArray[$i]);
```

and it is creating array like :

```
Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => John [2] => Ben [3] => Mike [Bob] => 3 [John] => 4 [Ben] => 3 [Mike] => 4)
```

Thats why it is showing count as 8

Answer (score 3):

You change the size of the array in the loop by pushing new Values into it. That's why

Answer (score 0):

Create new array instead of using same array

```
$nameArray = array("Bob", "John", "Ben", "Mike");
$nameLength = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameArray); $i++){
    $name = $nameArray[$i];
    $nameLength[$name] = strlen($nameArray[$i]);
    echo $nameArray[$i]."'s name is ".$nameLength[$name]." letters long <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$nameArray[$name] = strlen($nameArray[$i]);`

is the reason why you array length doubled. You add the the element length as new elements to the array. So it's length doubled.

May be you want a new array to store it's length with

`$nameLen[$name] = strlen($nameArray[$i]);`